# Are there any differences between 'finish' and 'finish with'?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is it like 'finish with' is more specific and more grammatically correct? Or are there any differences between the two?

> 1. It's time you finished your book.
> 2. It's time you finished with your book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are subtle differences.

In (1) -- "finished your book" means "finished reading" your book. You could use this to urge someone to finish reading their book, but the emphasis is that they read the entire thing.

In (2) -- "finished with your book" means "finished using" your book. This could be used if you are urging someone to stop using the book, maybe so that someone else can use it. The emphasis is on them to stop using their book, no matter how much of it they've read.

Comment: Another subtle difference is that you can "be finished with" a person (this is an idiom for tired of/disgusted with/disenchanted with and _don't want to see him/her anymore_). Or you could say "You and I are finished" (the relationship is done, we are _splitting up)_ But you can't  just "finish" a person.